# Get Test Coverage Sphinx "testcode" Directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, doctest, coverage.py

I have a number of tests in my Sphinx document. I choose to use the `.. testcode::` directive over the `.. doctest::` directive and standard `doctest` syntax because I want the output to resemble standard code blocks `.. code-block::`.

[image]

Using `sphinx.ext.doctest`, I can run my tests without any problems. The issue I am now having is getting test coverage. I looked at standard doctest and found a number of ways to accomplish this. One using `doctest.DocTestSuite` but this does not recognize the Sphinx `testcode`directives. I looked at `sphinx.ext.coverage` but it seems it is only for coverage of documentation. Is there a way to get a test coverage overview like that with `unitest` and `coverage` from Sphinx when using `testcode` directive.